# How do I check certain chars in string within quotation marks in python

Tags: python, string

I need to check if certain chars, for example [!,:] are within quotation marks in string, and not outside of them

```
The quick "brown!" fox jumps ":over" the lazy dog - valid string
The quick! "brown!" fox jumps ":over" the lazy, dog - invalid string
```

How do I check this?

Comment: Split string by double quotes and then check if your chars are in odd strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever used [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) ?

You can remove all of the words with quotes and look for your tokens.

```
import re

def all_tokens_quoted(string):
    quoted_words = re.compile('".*?"')
    tokens = re.compile('[!,:]')
    no_quotations = quoted_words.sub('', string)
    if tokens.search(no_quotations):
        return False
    return True

all_tokens_quoted('The quick "brown!" fox jumps ":over" the lazy dog')
>>> True
all_tokens_quoted('The quick! "brown!" fox jumps ":over" the lazy, dog')
>>> False
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like to check [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), which is really powerful on this.

```
import re

ifvalid = False
chars = ['!', ',', ':']
str1 = 'The quick "brown!" fox jumps ":over" the lazy dog - valid string'

nonquote = re.split('["].+?["]', str1)
quote = re.findall('["].+?["]', str1)

for word in quote:
    for ch in word:
        if ch in chars:
            ifvalid = True

for word in nonquote:
    for ch in word:
        if ch in chars:
            ifvalid = False

if ifvalid:
    print 'valid'
else:
    print 'invalid'
```

Comment: I'm sorry this is not what I expected. This code supposed to check if chars are within quotation marks, but I need to check if there are these chars in string they should be within quotation marks only.

Comment: @МихаилПавлов I'm sorry I've not read it clearly, I would change my code and make it works.

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expressions try this:

```
text = 'The quick "brown!" fox jumps ":over" the lazy dog'
text = text.split('"')
quotes = [text[i] for i in range (len(text)) if (i % 2 == 1)]
not_quotes = [text[i] for i in range (len(text)) if (i % 2 == 0)]
print(quotes, not_quotes)
```

This gives the correct output:

```
['brown!', ':over'] ['The quick ', ' fox jumps ', ' the lazy dog']
```

You can then split each of these in to a string and see if they contain the characters.

```
valid = True #assume valid

for not_quote in not_quotes:
    characters = list(not_quote)
    for character in characters:
        if character in ['!',',',':']:
            valid = False
```

Similar validation can be carried out on the strings in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = "The quick \"brown!\" fox jumps \":over\" the lazy dog - valid string"
str1_split = str1.split("\"")
for str in str1_split[1::2]:
    if str.find("!")>0:
        print "Found!"
        break
```